# Displaying a file in browser without revealing its location

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdf, flash

I am currently working on a project which can be best described as a online pdf library.

Users can log in and see a list of pdfs available. The user can click on one to 'check it out'

this then allows them to have access to view a pdf file for a specific time period after which it is no longer accessible.

there are two important rules:

1. The user can only view the pdf through the website and cannot copy it
2. After the time expires the user can no longer view the pdf

I was thinking of using swftools to convert the pdf to swf to disable the user from saving the pdf. But I still have a security issue:

**how do I display a swf in browser without revealing its location?**

thankyou for taking the time to answer this question. Please let me know if i need to specify anything.

Comment: In other words, "How do I lock down my PDF files with DRM so annoying and pervasive that my business will implode because customers hate the service with the burning passion of a hundred billion suns and go to a competitors site instead?"

Comment: Possible solution: tmp directory for swf files. You will copy it each time (and it's possible to share one of this files among several users that requested them), after some time just delete this file on CRON or something

Answer (score 0):

Use a timed URL.  Here's the insecure version:

```
  http://www.example.com?file=123&expires=2014-03-06
```

Now, to be less obvious, encode those two params into one variable and make it look like the filename:

```
  http://www.example.com/123-2014-03-06.pdf
```

But go one step further and hash/encode the values into something like a guid.

You can also do this on the server-side, by issuing a real guid and associating a filename and expiration time with that value.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, how is the URL timed?

Comment: Your server would need to parse the date from the url/hash and decide whether to serve the file.